# how to set cron job if using codeigniter in cpanel?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, codeigniter-4

I have a controller called Buy and it has a live method. How to install a cronjob if using codeigniter? I use codeigniter 4,and l use cpanel.

```
php - q /home/kuslon/kuslon/app/Controllers/Services/Buy.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### STEPS

1. Create a command-line route in `app/Config/Routes.php`. I.e:

```php
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
// ...

$routes->cli("cli/ship-product/(:segment)", "Services\Buy::ship/$1");

// ...
```

Where:

`cli/ship-product/(:segment)` - Represents your route. The `(:segment)` is *optional* depending on if your Controller method requires an argument or not.

`Buy` - Represents your Controller.

`ship` - Represents your Controller method.

`$1` - Represents the optional `(:segment)` to be forwarded to the first Controller method's argument if in case it requires one. You may omit it if your Controller method doesn't require any arguments.

*Notice the use of [CLI-only routing](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/cli/cli.html#cli-only-routing) with the help of [`->cli(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/a3e7eeabed0a488e4b17309ed1411392c4daef05/system/Router/RouteCollection.php#L947)*.

2. Run your cron job.

```php
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/kuslon/kuslon/public/index.php cli ship-product "ed053cb1-29a4-42f2-a17e-3109fa4d80fe"
```

Where:

`-q` - Represents [quiet-mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php). Suppress HTTP header output.

`/home/kuslon/kuslon/public/index.php` - Represents the absolute path to your project's `index.php` file. This assumes that the first `kuslon` in the path represents your ***Cpanel username*** and the second `kuslon` represents your project root folder.

`cli` - Represents the *first* section of the command-line route you defined earlier.

`ship-product` - Represents the *second* section of the command-line route.

`"ed053cb1-29a4-42f2-a17e-3109fa4d80fe"` - Represents the *third* optional section of the command-line route that may be required by your Controller method.

3. Sample Controller.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Services;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Buy extends BaseController
{

    public function ship(string $uuid)
    {
//        echo  "{$uuid}";
    }

}
```

Resource: [Running via the Command Line](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/cli/cli.html)

##### Addendum:

If in case all your routes pass through an Authentication filter, you may want to **exclude** these command-line based routes in `app/Config/Filters.php`. I.e: As you may notice below, I've [excluded all routes starting with](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html#globals) `cli/*` from the `authfilter`.

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

use App\Filters\AuthenticationFilter;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    // ...
    public $aliases = [
        //...
        'authfilter' => AuthenticationFilter::class
    ];

    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            //...
            'authfilter' => [
                'except' => ['cli/*']
            ]
        ],
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Main thing You must do is check if request is from command Line and not from A browser in your controller using this [***is_cli()***](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/common_functions.html#is_cli)  function .
then you can set the cron job in Cpanel .

good luck