# CI4 Cron Job in CPanel for installation without index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface, codeigniter-4

I have a Cron Controller that I would like to run from CPanel's cron job functionality, however my installation does not have an index.php file as I have used mod_rewrite on my .htaccess file so it doesn't show in my url.

I've read the [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/cli/cli.html) on running it through cli and can only get an input in the error_log using
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/subdomain.domain.com/app/Controllers/Cron.php`

I'm getting the following error:

> [05-Oct-2022 21:36:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'CodeIgniter\Controller' not found in /home/user/subdomain.domain.com/app/Controllers/Cron.php:7
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/user/subdomain.domain.com/app/Controllers/Cron.php on line 7

This is how my Controller is setup

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\CronModel;

class Cron extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $db = db_connect();
        $this->cronModel = new CronModel($db);
    }
    
    /* 
     * Function to start cronjob if it's time
     */
    public function index(){
       $this->cronModel->run();
    }

}
```

No other cli reaches the controller and I keep getting this error.

EDIT: I have this in my Routes file:
`$routes->cli('cron/index/(:segment)', 'Cron::index/$1');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set cron job if using codeigniter in cpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71822869/how-to-set-cron-job-if-using-codeigniter-in-cpanel)

Comment: I added the exception to the filter file, because indeed I needed it, but otherwise the cli example on the question doesn't even reach my Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work. There was a rewrite on the .htaccess file on Codeigniter's root. So basically I added the rewrite rule to the cli path and it worked, like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/subdomain.domain.com/rewrite_rule_path cron run
```